# Springs/Struts, dynamic content and UIScrollView not correctly scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am having trouble with dynamic cells being added to a dynamic UITableView inside a UIScrollView.  The scrollview doesnt scroll all the way to the bottom.  Below you will see the max scroll, hiding two more cells at the end of the table.  I am using autolayout and not sure how to fix this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [self setTableHeight];
    return [player.metas count];
}

- (void)setTableHeight
{
    long tableHeightCalculated = 44 * [player.metas count];
    metaTableView.frame = CGRectMake(metaTableView.frame.origin.x, metaTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                 metaTableView.frame.size.width,  tableHeightCalculated);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you're using a static table view, you shouldn't even be implementing any of the data source methods (like numberOfRowsInSection).

Comment: Its a dynamic table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the contentSize of UIScrollView correctly.
You should scroll to view all of your contents if you set contentSize and the UIScrollView's frame correctly

Please try this

```
- (void)setTableHeight
{
    long tableHeightCalculated = 44 * [player.metas count];
    CGFloat diffHeight = tableHeightCalculated - metaTableView.frame.size.height;
    metaTableView.frame = CGRectMake(metaTableView.frame.origin.x, metaTableView.frame.origin.y,
                                     metaTableView.frame.size.width,  tableHeightCalculated);
    _uiScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_uiScrollView.contentSize.width, (_uiScrollView.contentSize.height + diffHeight));
}
```

Comment: `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.uiScrollView layoutIfNeeded];
    self.uiScrollView.contentSize = self.uiView.bounds.size;
}`

Comment: What is your UITableView's height in the design view? Did you set it for amount of your cells * cellHeight? If not you should update the contentSize when you created cells. But if you've done all of these, the autolayout maybe the problem like you said.

Comment: Height is 156 in design mode, but has 44 x 5 rows.

Comment: So, there is 2 ways to solve this.
1. If your table will show exactly 5 rows and your cell's height is exactly 44, you should set the table height in design view to 220.
2. If your table maybe show less or more cells than 5 rows or the cell's height is dynamic, you must set the new table's height when each cell is created and don't forget to calculate and set the new contentSize of your scroll view.

Comment: As you can see above I do set the table size of my dynamic table based on the number of cells.  I calculate the height be taking 44 * # or rows.  Where should I set the contentSize of my scrollview after that if I am already doing that in viewDidLayoutSubViews.